# In Google Sheets add all the rows above the current one

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to add all the numbers in a given column of all the rows before the total row. Let's assume my column H contains number. If I have 15 rows, I'd do `sum(H1:H15)` in my sixteenth (total) row.

But when I add rows in between, my formula doesn't get updated, so I have to think of updating it to include all the rows.

I thought of using indirect to determine the index of the total row and doing the sum up to that row minus 1. That gave me:

```
=round(sum(indirect(concatenate("H2:H",row()-1))))
```

- We can ignore round() here - it's just to given the nearest integer for my sum
- sum adds all the rows
- indirect lets me convert a string into an address so it can be used in my sum function
- concatenate adds all the strings together
- "H2:H" is the beginning part of my range
- row() returns my current row and so row()-1 represents the last row I want to sum

Is there a more elegant way?

Thanks

Comment: using =SUM(H1:H15) should update itself if you "add rows in between." The only case when it wouldn't do so is if you added a row above Row 1 (i.e., clicked to select all of Row 1 and then chose "Insert 1 below." Without seeing your sheet, I can't tell you anything beyond that I am unable to produce this behavior.

Comment: Row 1 specifically?

Comment: I think I usually either select the last row before the total row and then insert after or the total row and then insert before

Comment: I see. If you want to continue this approach (not recommended), you could insert at the row TWO above the total, copy and paste the amount that moved down into the gap, and add your new amount above the total. But the standard approach among experts is to put your totals at the TOP of columns, above the headers (both because of what you're experiencing and so that you don't have to scroll to see it).

Comment: Ha, that's a good point re. scrolling: I always want to freeze the bottom row

Comment: I don't think there's a more elegant way than the one you described, in order to make sure the row indexes don't get messed up. At most, you could get rid of `concatenate` and use `&` instead: `=sum(indirect("H2:H"&row()-1))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OFFSET` for that like this:

`=SUM(OFFSET(B6, 0, 0, ROW() - ROW(B6), 1))`

[image]